# unit test for method that use other methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm new to unit test and confusing how write unit test method like this:

```
public Boolean BeepInTime(Interfaces.IDateTime time,TimeSpan beepTime)
{
    Interfaces.IBeep beep= new Beep();
    var h = time.GetTime();
    if (h == beepTime)
    {
       return beep.Beeping();
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }
}

public Boolean Beeping()
{
    try
    {
      SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
      return true;
    }
    catch
    {
      return false;
    }
}
```

When testing `BeepInTime` , I'd like (`beep.Beeping()`) not running. I read about stub and think in this case I should use stub but it is confusing about how to do this. 
Could you send some source with simple example about stub.

Comment: can't give you and example, because is a lot of work. You have to do a lot of changes. You need to study Ninject first. And run some eamples before you do your own test

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278593/junit-test-class-for-the-following-code/12280527

Comment: Alberto: What a nonsense. You dont have to use Ninject to unit test code or to write testable code.

Comment: @Peri yes is not need, but, as annahita described his problem, I think  decoupling with dependency injection is what he needs. And ninject is the best way... In my opinion

Comment: @Alberto: Why Ninject? You don't have to use IoC Container at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is - dependency injection.

Each time you do or see `... = new ...();` (construction) think of dependency injection, basically explicit instantiation introduces dependencies and then sometimes writing unit tests for such a code becomes not trivial.

So instead of explicit instantiation of `Beep` class just inject it. What is good - you already have an interface which abstracts this class - `IBeep`, this would allow you creatign and injecting a mock instead of a real class instance when writing unit tests.

```
public Boolean BeepInTime(Interfaces.IBeep beeper, TimeSpan beepTime) 
{
    var h = time.GetTime();            
    if (h == beepTime)            
    {                 
        return beep.Beeping();            
    } 

    return false;
}
```

Ans just imagine how this technique is helpful in case of injecting DB access service or web-service, you do not need a real DB or web-service while writing unit tests - you just mock DB/web service and that's it.

Example using RhinoMocks:

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IBeep>();

// setup Beeping() return value == true
mock.Expect(m => m.Beeping()).Return(true);
var isBeepInTime = BeepInTime(mock, timeSpan)
```

Comment: Dependency injection is *a* solution (and a good and popular one at that), but it is not the only solution.  The mocking bit is the key part.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of different ways to resolve this.  The simpliest way is to pass an interface to Beep into the class (either through constructor or method itself).

```
public Boolean BeepInTime(Interfaces.IDateTime time,TimeSpan beepTime, Interfaces.IBeep beep) 
{ 
    var h = time.GetTime(); 
    if (h == beepTime) 
    { 
        return beep.Beeping(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return false; 
    } 
   }
```

In your unit test you create a mock IBeep object and pass in the mock.  There are lots of third party mocking frameworks out there also so you do not have to create your own mocks.  I personally use Moq and it is a good one.  RhinoMocks is also popular.  Both are free.

If you do not want to have to create the Beep class in your production code then you could do this...

```
public Boolean BeepInTime(Interfaces.IDateTime time,TimeSpan beepTime, Interfaces.IBeep beep = null) 
{ 
    if (beep == null)
         beep = new Beep();

    var h = time.GetTime(); 
    if (h == beepTime) 
    { 
        return beep.Beeping(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return false; 
    } 
   }
```

NOTE:  I would not normally pass the interface into the constructor and assign it to a field rather then pass it into the method, especially if the class is called from many methods).  There are many other ways to do this including using NInject.  I am just providing these examples to give you a sneak peek into how it is done.

I would recommend doing a few days of research on the internet looking into these things before deciding on any one method.

Comment: +1 for concentrating on the mock rather than on dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to remove the dependency to `Beep` from the `BeepInTime` method like this:

```
public Boolean BeepInTime(Interfaces.IDateTime time,TimeSpan beepTime, Interfaces.IBeep beep)
       {           
           var h = time.GetTime();
           if (h == beepTime)
           {

               return beep.Beeping();
           }
           else
           {
               return false;
           }

       }
```

Then you can Mock out the IBeep impementation when testing using something like Moq:

```
//Arrange
var mockBeep = new Mock<Interfaces.IBeep>();
mockBeep.Setup(b => b.Beeping())
.Returns(true);

// Act

var result = myClass.BeepInTime(myTime, myBeepTime, mockBeep.Object);

...
```

Comment: +1 for concentrating on the mock rather than on dependency injection.